# Kineticjs text padding interferes with mouseover events

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am trying to tween the color of a `Kinetic.Rect` when the mouse moves over it. I also have a piece of text defined at the same location. It seems that adding padding to a `Kinetic.Text` interferes with mouseover events.

I have created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/d5pbK/
I have two padding statements one at line 40 and one at line 45.

The way the fiddle is right now when I move the mouse in the blue rectangle its changes color but if you move the mouse over the horizontal text extents then the rectangle does NOT change color.

Also if you activate any of the padding statements then only when I place the mouse over the orange border, only then does the rectangle change colors.

I would like the rectangle to change colors when the mouse is over it irrespectively of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Kinetic.Text` element takes up the same space as the `Kinetic.Rect` element when `padding` is added to the text.

So instead of adding the events to the `Kinetic.Rect`, add them to the `Kinetic.Text`

Updated fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/MZ57d/